# Angular get reference to $scope variable from select

Tags: angularjs

I have a list :

```
$scope.selectlist = ["list1","list2","list3"];
```

Once I choose an element, I should display the list according to the select value knowing that I have these lists in my scope :

```
$scope.list1
$scope.list2
$scope.list3
```

Any ideas to make it work ?

I thought doing :

```
    <div ng-repeat="i in selectedPerson">
       {{selectedPerson}}
    </div>
```

will work.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/81t6cbjw/68/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ng-repeat variable is `i` so You should put `{{i}}` instead of `{{selectedPerson}}`.

You should also get proper list from the scope, based on `$scope.selectedPerson` value. Try this :

`$scope.getList = function() {
    return $scope[$scope.selectedPerson];
}`

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/81t6cbjw/69/)

Answer (score 2):

You can create a variable that holds all lists `$scope.allLists` and after a list is selected `$scope.selectedList`, just use the following syntax `$scope.allLists[$scope.selectedList]`.

For example `$scope.allLists = { list1: [...], list2: [...], list3: [...] }` and `$scope.selectedList = 'list1'`.

Answer (score 1):

Change your template to this:

```
<div ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="FirstCtrl">
        <select ng-options="p for p in selectlist" ng-model="selectedPerson"></select>

        <div ng-repeat="i in this[selectedPerson]">
           {{i}}
        </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use javascript variable instead of $scope for your list1, list2, list3.

```
var list1 = [1,2,3,4,5];

var list2 = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g'];

var list3 = ["hi","bye","whatever"];

$scope.selectlist = [list1,list2,list3];
```

http://jsfiddle.net/81t6cbjw/70/